# How do I change my Field of View?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I know that I can kind of adjust my field of view by switching from a 4:3 resolution to a 16:10 or 16:9 resolution.  Is there any way that I can just set the field of view to the maximum allowable width?

Comment: I know that the source engine allows a settable parameter for the field of view, but I'm not sure how to expose it. I know that some source games allow up to 90 degrees, but I'd bet it's configurable for all source games, but I'm not sure how high it goes.

Comment: For general FOV, type fov (70 - 90) into the console. For weapon/model fov, type viewmodel_fov (no limit, but the default is 60. Most people use 90. Over 1000 your weapon is invisible).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a question on the now defunct teamfortress2fort.com

> It's in the Multiplayer tab of the options window

Answer (score 4):

It now appears to be limited to 70 degrees for TF2, much to my annoyance (I play on a triple monitor setup with 15:4 aspect ratio, and everything is severely distorted at the edges of the screen).

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can!
in console

```
fov 90
```

(~ = console that you need to enable in multiplayer options)

at least this worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

To set your field of view set to 90, in the type console `fov_desired 90`. You can only go  between 75 and 90, anything above 90 is considered cheating.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your fov with fov_desired. It will only go up to 90.

The viewmodel_fov, however can be beyond 90. This command only affects what is in front of your screen (gun, hands,etc) instead of how much you can see.

- More viewmodel_fov, the less your guns and your hands cover up your screen.
- More fov_desired, the more you can actually see.

Now while both fov_desired and viewmodel_fov will help with what you see, they are not the same thing.

This video explains it better:

Comment: Why has someone voted to delete this? It's a good explanation of the differences between the two commands and how to combine both to achieve the desired result. None of the other answers do this.

Answer (score -1):

You can go more than 90 or less than 70 and still can play. This is not considered cheating. Enter this in the console `viewmodel_fov <fov number>`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adjusting `viewmodel_fov`

Comment: This does not add anything new.